# theano and scikit-neuralnetwork testing error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, theano

When I using "python examples/plot_mlp.py --parama activation", the error is happend. Please help me to fix it.(Ubuntu 16.04/ python 2.7.12/ theano 1.0.2/ sklearn 0.19.1)

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:41:             
DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of
the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and     
functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators 
are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 
0.20."This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)        
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "examples/plot_mlp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from sknn import mlp
  File "/home/admin/scikit-neuralnetwork/sknn/mlp.py", line 18, in      
<module>
    import theano
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line     
88, in <module>
    from theano.configdefaults import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", 
line 47, in <module>
    in_c_key=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/configparser.py",     
line 281, in AddConfigVar    
configparam.fullname)
AttributeError: ('This name is already taken', 'floatX')
```

Comment: Read the last line, are you using floatX somewhere in your code?

Comment: The test program above, named plot_mlp.py, is provided by  scikit-neuralnetwork packet.